# Middleware that puts data in the request vault

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-wai

I'm trying to write a WAI middleware that puts some data in the request's vault, but it seems I'm missing something because I can't look it up later. Even the simplest middleware fail:

```
fooMW :: Middleware
fooMW app req sendResponse = do
  k <- Vault.newKey @Int
  let d = 42
      newVault = Vault.insert k d (vault req)
  app (req {vault = newVault}) $ \res -> sendResponse res
```

Which I then use like this:

```
main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware fooMW
  get "/foo" $ do
    k <- liftIO $ Vault.newKey @Int
    v <- vault <$> request
    let d = Vault.lookup k v
    liftIO $ print d
    json $ object ["foo" .= ("bar" :: Text)]
```

When doing `http :3000/foo` I expect the server to print `Just 42` but in prints `Nothing`, suggesting that something's wrong in `fooMW`. I guess I'm missing something crucial about how to write middlewares, or how to use *vault*, but what?

Comment: The code seems to assume that the two invocations of `Vault.newKey` return the *same* key, but I'm not sure that's the case. Perhaps you could create the key once, in `main`, and then share it between the middleware and the handler.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the case. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Vault.newKey` produces a different key every time, so it should be called once and shared instead of being called every time the key is used. Thanks @danidiaz